# Se puede llamar un WSDL de manera local usando PHP

Tags: php, webservice, soap

Estoy aprendiendo a usar Soapclient en PHP y me arroja un error al tratar de consumir un servicio:

> https://e-beta.sunat.gob.pe/ol-ti-itcpfegem-beta/billService?wsdl

Esto me retorna el siguiente error

> **Parsing WSDL BillServicePortBinding already defined**

Según lo que estuve investigando, es porque PHP no soporta doble namespaces, ahora se dice que la solución es descargar el wsdl de manera local y consumirlo. la pregunta es..¿Se puede hacer de manera local? ya que php

```
$client = new SoapClient(null, array('location' => "http://localhost/soap.php", 'uri' => "http://test-uri/"));
```

Desde ya gracias.

Comment: Si se puede. De esa manera he estado enviando comprobantes de pago a la SUNAT en producción. En mi blog detallé el proceso: https://drmad.org/blog/cronicas-de-una-facturacion-electronica-desde-php-anunciada.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto se debe a un bug del PHP [#45282](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45282)

Debes implementar este paquete [SOAP PERL](http://pear.php.net/package/SOAP).

Si puedes tener el webservice ejecutándose desde Eclipse y lo has construido bien puedes obtener una instancia de la siguiente manera:

```
new SoapClient("http://localhost:8080/ruta/services/Gestor?wsdl");
```